# What is the replacement for the use of DENSE_RANK() OVER Partition in Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Below is the example scenario

```
SELECT *  FROM
        (SELECT RId,rCode,OCode,PClass,MType,ECode,Status,FType,
          CTimeStamp, Id,asofdate,datime,
      MIN(rid) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY CTimeStamp DESC, asofdate DESC, da_time DESC, id) OVER (PARTITION BY RId,rCode,OCode,PClass,MType,ECode,Status,FType) Min_rid,
      MIN(sdate) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY CTimeStamp DESC, asofdate DESC, da_time DESC, id) OVER (PARTITION BY RId,rCode,OCode,PClass,MType,ECode,Status,FType) Min_Sub_Date,
          DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY RId,rCode,OCode,PClass,MType,ECode,Status,FType) ORDER BY CTimeStamp  DESC, asofdate DESC, datime DESC, id) rank
        FROM sometable aaa
        ) rn1
      WHERE rn1.rank = 1
```

It takes a longer execution time if table has more than million records.

I would like to know the ways to optimize this.

Comment: Apply `INDEX` in a required column

Comment: Include the table schema in this question - including any indexes. As mentioned already, you probably need another index somewhere.

Comment: Apart from the index part, anything can be done with query?

Comment: An index does not help here, because there is no `WHERE` clause, i.e. the full table has to be read in any case. So, there are not so many  ways to optimize your query.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `PARALLEL` option, [so we have multiple process doing the work in parallel.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/parallel002.htm)

```
SELECT /*+ parallel(4) */ 
 ...
 ...
FROM 
sometable aaa
```

From [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174),

> If the objects being queried have the parallel attribute, and if you
>   specify an analytic function with the query_partition_clause, then the
>   function computations are parallelized as well.

**Note:** Please be careful in choosing the `PARALLEL` option in production environment, as it might consume lot of CPU, which would hinder the performance of other online adhoc queries.